# Create new child in Dom

Tags: java, xml, dom, architecture

I have created test class that created DOM object ,currently I created some attributes 
Hard coded ,for example I have create element name structure and for the structure we have attributes,I have created different class that handle the attribute with constructor .

These is the code from the main method

```
Properties properties = new Properties(document);
          Element Property = properties.getProperty();

 Properties.setProperty(Property, "product_id","10", "Pro ID");
 Type.appendChild(Property);

   Properties properties1 = new Properties(document);
    Element Property1 = properties1.getProperty();

   Properties.setProperty(Property1, "curr","5", "Curr Code");
   Type.appendChild(Property1);
```

The code in the constructor is

```
public Properties(Document document) {
    Property = document.createElement(PROPERTY);
}
```

As you can see for create new property I have created element **property and property1** etc hard coded,which is problematic since what will happen
If I will have table that with list of properties with there data ,how should I handle it?
I am not sure if the constructor is the right solution and my question is how to do that better ?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do.

If you want to create a DOM so that you can test your classes that build DOM's, then simply hard-coding calls will work just fine.  You just have to make sure you use enough combinations of calls to thoroughly test you API.

If, on the other hand, you need to create a DOM so that you can then proceed to test your API's that require some sort of DOM input, you might want to consider simply creating those DOM's in the form of XML documents and then using the org.w3c.dom API's to create the DOM from the XML.

Comment: HI Chris ,Currently I am using it like unit test and my question is how to create new property dynamically instead of using property1 property2 etc if i got list of property from 1-100...